# What are the limitations on the use of output registers in avr-gcc inline assembly?

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, avr

Output register in inline assembly must be declared with the "=" constraint, meaning "write-only" [1]. What exactly does this mean - is it truly forbidden to read and modify them within the assembly? For example, consider this code:

```
uint8_t one ()
{
    uint8_t res;
    asm("ldi %[res],0\n"
        "inc %[res]\n"
        : [res] "=r" (res)
    );
    return res;
}
```

The assembly sets the output register to 0 then increments it. Is this breaking the "write-only" constraint?

**UPDATE**

I'm seeing problems where my inline asm breaks when I change it to work directly on an output register, as opposed to using r16 for the computation and finally mov'ing r16 into the output register. The code is here: http://ideone.com/JTpYma . It prints results to serial, you just need to define F_CPU and BAUD. The problem appears only when using gcc-4.8.0 and not using gcc-4.7.2.

[1] http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/inline_asm.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't care whether you read it or not, it just won't put the initial value of the variable into the register. Your example is entirely legal, but people often wrongly expect to get result `2` from this code:

```
uint8_t one ()
{
    uint8_t res = 1;
    asm("inc %[res]\n"
        : [res] "=r" (res)
    );
    return res;
}
```

Since it's only an output constraint, the initial value of `res` is not guaranteed to be loaded into the register. In fact, the initializer may even be optimized away on the assumption that the asm block will overwrite it anyway. The above code is compiled to this by my version of avr-gcc:

```
inc r24
ret
```

As you can see, the compiler indeed removed loading `1` into `res` and hence into `r24` thus producing undefined result.

---

**Update**

The problem with the updated program in the question is that it also has an input register operand. By default the compiler assumes that all inputs are consumed before the outputs are assigned so it's safe to allocate overlapping registers. That's clearly not the case for your example. You should use an "*early clobber*" modifier (`&`) for the output. This is what the manual has to say about that:

> `&` Means (in a particular alternative) that this operand is an
>   earlyclobber operand, which is modified before the instruction is
>   finished using the input operands. Therefore, this operand may not lie
>   in a register that is used as an input operand or as part of any
>   memory address.

Nobody said gcc inline asm was easy :D

Comment: You may be wrong here, see my edit. Or it's just a compiler bug.